# How to get radio button value after onclick event in prototype

Tags: prototype

I am using the following piece of code in the prototype js-

```
 $('co-payment-form').on('change', 'input:radio', function() {
    alert(this.value);
 });
```

I want to get the radio button value after clicking the radio button. I tried this.value but value is coming undefined. Please help me how to get the value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code.

```
$('co-payment-form').on('change', 'input:radio', function(el) {
   alert($(el.target).value);

});
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'val' "

Comment: Can you please suggest me?

Comment: No...still getting the undefined value

Comment: $(this).pluck('value') try this one.

Comment: Getting this error again: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'pluck'

Comment: hi can anyone suggest me about this issue?

Comment: i have updated code please try again.at this time its work i am sure.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('co-payment-form').on('change', 'input:radio', function(e) {
   console.log(e.target.value);
});
```