# JavaScript for loop innerHTML returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, for-loop

I have been racking my brain all morning about this. In my HTML code I have a list containing letters a - j and want to console log the letter when it is clicked.

I have created a `for` loop to run through the nodelist and I can get the script to console log out the number of the element that is being clicked but as soon as I try and get the `innerHTML` or anything like that it returns undefined.

But when I just type `el[3].innerHTML` for example into the console it returns the letter I want.

Please help me understand why just because it's going through a `for` loop does it make it undefined?

I'm not just looking for the solution but also to learn why it's happening so I can become a better coder.

Thanks!

Code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var el = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', function(f) {
    return function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(f.innerHTML);
    }
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: Is the script on the top of the page before the li has been written to the page? Note also letters are not elements of an element, you should only see a test node string, if there are no other elements.

Comment: Is possible that f is not defined inside the function, can you put also the html or a plunker example to make a quick test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get radio button value after onclick event in prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661932/how-to-get-radio-button-value-after-onclick-event-in-prototype)

Comment: `f === i` and `i` is an integer, which doesn't have the said property.

Answer (score 1):

You miss name of variable at :

console.log(this.innerHTML);

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var el = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

console.log(el)

  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click",function(f){

    return function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    };
  }(i));
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which makes the entire IIFE unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `i` as your argument into the function, `f` takes on the value of `i` so when you try to get `f.innerHTML` you're attempting to get the HTML from an integer, rather than from the element that was clicked.

You can use `this` to target the element that was clicked.  Here is a working example:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var el = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click",function(f){

    return function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    };
  }(i));
}
```

```html
<ul>List
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

*Edited with corrected information thanks to @Teemu.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example, I think it was problem with passing correct element

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
   var el = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

   for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) {
   el[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){

     return function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.innerHTML);
   };
 }(el[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your Main Problem

As alredy mentiont in the comments by [@teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) your `f` is the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object. And to access `innerHtml` you need to access `target` befor.

### Idea

Currently you have n `<li>` elements an `eventListener`. You can have only one on your `<ul>` to have a *cleaner code base*.

#### Code

When you add the eventListener to `<ul>` you can access each clicked element in it via `event.target`.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

list.addEventListener('click', logInnerHtml)

function logInnerHtml(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(
        event.currentTarget.innerHtml
    )
}
```

#### Example

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

list.addEventListener('click', logInnerHtml)

function logInnerHtml(event) {
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Umh ... The event object was an incorrect statement from me, there's a new, more correct comment, has been there for almost an hour  by now.